# Blackberry http post request length trouble

Tags: blackberry

I have a blackberry program that sends data using http post requests to a backend. Now the code works perfectly on my simulators (OS 5/6/7) and even on real devices, but on some other devices in some countries, the connection fails when using 3g with http error code 400 (Bad Request) but over WiFi it's ok.. After investigating, i realised that those telecom operators' bis-b proxies were "blocking"/"rejecting" the post request because of the size (>7kb). The problem is i can't shorten the request size, so any ideas on how to go about this? Any would be highly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**
This is the connection string used when connecting through the BIS.

```
deviceside=false;connectionUID=GPMDSXXXX;ConnectionType=mds-public (XXXX varies from network to network)
```

On further inspection, I realised that the "working" connections use the BIS_B TransportDescriptor type (5) to connect whereas the "failing" connections are using TCP_CELLULAR (1) to connect. 
i.e. calling `connectionDescriptor.getTransportDescriptor().getTransportType()` for the working connections gives 5 and for the failing ones gives 1. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Then do not use BIS and use direct TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use HTTPS. In this case carrier can't sniff what exactly is going inside.

Comment: Interesting, so by using https the carrier won't even "read" the size of the data?

Comment: Correct. They could measure amount of traffic that is going to specific connection. But it doesn't give them clear picture what is going on.

Comment: Noted with thanks. I was thinking what of a multipart http post, would that work?